# H2 embedded DB does't return proper results when using LIMIT AND OFFSET

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I am using the below query to do pagination of my table.

```
select * 
from TABLE_NAME 
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 10
```

My table has 12 rows. When I run this query from Squirrel, it returns response but when I use JDBC connection to fetch it doesn't return data.

Same query works fine if I use LIMIT AS 14 AND OFFSET 4. (No issue with my JDBC).

Java code:

```
List<DataPoolEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
try {

    String fetch = "select * from TABLENAME LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET " + offset;


    java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(fetch);

    java.sql.ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();

    list = generateDataPoolEntityList(result); (custom code) - ignore this
    result.close();
    stmt.close();
    return list;
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

Comment: `limit` and `offset` without an `order by` makes no sense - no wonder you don't get what you expect. And if it doesn't work from within your Java code, you have to show us the Java code as well.

Comment: I have order as well, my full query : select * 
from TABLE_NAME 
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 10 ORDER BY ID

Comment: Not returning data (or not the data expect), usually means that either you are connecting to different databases, or you are viewing data that was created in the current transaction and hasn't been committed so it isn't visible to other transactions. Also what do you mean with _"works fine if I use LIMIT AS 14 AND OFFSET 4"_? As shown that clause is a syntax error.

Comment: my actual query :select * from TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ID LIMIT 4 OFFSET 10

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I don't have any write operations or any uncommitted transaction before fetch query. If i use the query : select * from TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ID LIMIT 14 OFFSET 4 - it returns 12 records, where as if i use the query : select * from TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ID LIMIT 4 OFFSET 8 - it doesnt return any result, where as i am expecting 4 records

Comment: There's no difference between running the query in Squirrel (JDBC based) or JDBC directly. You're probably connecting to different databases / datasets, or your Squirrel connection has uncommitted rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

`Order by` should be before `limit`. [See the specification](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html).

Comment: it is before limit : select * from TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ID LIMIT 4 OFFSET 1

Comment: Are you sure that the ResultSet is empty? Try `... java.sql.ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(); result.last(); System.out.println(result.getRow()); ...`

Comment: Same table results if I use SELECT *